# Нет связей между моделями БД во время выполнения ASP.NET 5 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

У меня есть SQL Server БД и ASP.NET Core 5 MVC проект. В этом проекте я за"scaffold"ил контекст и модели для работы с БД.

Они выглядят примерно так:

```
public partial class Character
{
        public Character()
        {
            Battles = new HashSet<Battle>();
            CharactersInDungeons = new HashSet<CharactersInDungeon>();
            CharactersWeapons = new HashSet<CharactersWeapon>();
        }
        
        [DisplayName("Имя")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        [DisplayName("Уровень")]
        public int? Level { get; set; }
        
        [DisplayName("Здоровье")]
        public int? Health { get; set; }
        
        [DisplayName("Сила атаки")]
        public int? Attack { get; set; }
        
        [DisplayName("Класс")]
        public string Class { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Battle> Battles { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<CharactersInDungeon> CharactersInDungeons { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<CharactersWeapon> CharactersWeapons { get; set; }
} 

public class Battle
{
        [DisplayName("Имя персонажа")]
        public string CharacterName { get; set; }
        
        [DisplayName("Название монстра")]
        public string MonsterName { get; set; }
        
        [DisplayName("Название оружия")]
        public string WeaponName { get; set; }

        public virtual Character CharacterNameNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual Monster MonsterNameNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual Weapon WeaponNameNavigation { get; set; }
}
```

Классы содержат ссылки друг на друга, например, класс Character содержит ссылку на коллекцию Battle, и когда в контроллере я пытаюсь получить связанные с персонажем битвы, мне говорит, что там пусто, хотя в БД все связи есть. Когда же я дебажу код и раскрываю каждый DBSet в контексте, перед тем, как получить персонажа, как здесь:

[image: Раскрытый DBSet в контексте во время дебаггинга]

Все связи, которые должны быть между таблицами, появляются и все битвы персонажа появляются.

Я пытаюсь получить коллекцию битв вот так:

```
List<Battle> battles= new List<Battle>();

var character = await _context.Characters.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Name == id);

foreach (var battle in character.Battles)
{
    battles.Add(battle);
}
```

Как вы можете видеть, персонаж должен иметь ссылку на все битвы внутри себя и это должно выглядеть вот так:

[image: Как должны выглядеть коллекция битв персонажа]

Есть 3 битвы персонажа Antoswka240. С другой стороны, в битве есть ссылка на персонажа Antoswka240.
Вот связи в БД:

[image: Связи БД MS SQL]

**UPD1:**
В OnModelCreating в контексте у меня так же содержится след. код:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Character>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Name);

            entity.Property(e => e.Name).HasMaxLength(255);

            entity.Property(e => e.Attack).HasDefaultValueSql("((0))");

            entity.Property(e => e.Class)
                .HasMaxLength(15)
                .IsFixedLength(true);

            entity.Property(e => e.Health).HasDefaultValueSql("((0))");

            entity.Property(e => e.Level).HasDefaultValueSql("((0))");
            
            entity.ToTable("Characters");
        });
    ...
    Ещё код
    ...
        modelBuilder.Entity<Battle>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => new { e.CharacterName, e.MonsterName, e.WeaponName });

            entity.Property(e => e.CharacterName).HasMaxLength(255);

            entity.Property(e => e.MonsterName).HasMaxLength(255);

            entity.Property(e => e.WeaponName).HasMaxLength(255);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.CharacterNameNavigation)
                .WithMany(p => p.Battles)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.CharacterName)
                .HasPrincipalKey(c => c.Name)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                .IsRequired(true);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.MonsterNameNavigation)
                .WithMany(p => p.Battles)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.MonsterName)
                .HasPrincipalKey(m => m.Name)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                .IsRequired(true);

            entity.HasOne(d => d.WeaponNameNavigation)
                .WithMany(p => p.Battles)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.WeaponName)
                .HasPrincipalKey(w => w.Name)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                .IsRequired(true);
            
            entity.ToTable("Battles");
        });
```

Когда я создал новую запись в battle, со ссылкой на Character, Monster и Weapon в самом коде, а не БД, без имён, то все связи у каждой сущности были, так же в БД появилась новая строчка с их именами т.е. всё сохранилось. Но, когда я перезапустил приложение, все связи пропали и опять у Character было 0 Battle.(В БД запись есть)

**UPD2:**

Скриншот из MSSQL Server со связями между таблицами
[image: Скриншот из MSSQL Server со связями между таблицами]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте Include для этого:

```
       List<Battle> battles = new List<Battle>();

        var character = await _context.Characters
            .Include(_ => _.Battles)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Name == id);

        foreach (var battle in character.Battles)
        {
            battles.Add(battle);
        }
```

Вот тут можно почитать подробнее:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, попробовал Include вместе с и без ThenInclude, а так же попробовал Navigation.AutoInculde в modelbuilder, ничего не получилось. Обновил свой вопрос, дополнив информацией modelbuilder.

Comment: PK нужны в каждой из ваших таблиц и FK, по которым будут они связываться. Пример: Table Character нужна колонка Id int PRIMARY KEY, а табличке Battle соответственно должна быть колонка IdCharacter int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY со ссылкой на ключ в таблице Character

Comment: @Konst прикрепил скриншот из MSSQL Server, всё так и стоит.

Comment: PK должны быть типа int, не nvarchar/varchar. CharacterName можете просто сделать уникальным ключом, если вам надо. Т.е. нужно добавить колонку Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)

Comment: @Konst к сожалению не помогло, добавил у каждой сущности id и поменял все ссылки в других таблицах с имён на id, но при просмотре отдельного персонажа, ссылок на битвы, всё так же нет, как и на другие сущности.

Comment: Не знаю, как это работает, но решил ещё раз попробовать с Include и всё получилось. Спасибо вам